# Why am I getting an error when I try to create the Scoreboard object with an array?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

```
import java.io.*;

public class SaveAndLoad
{
    private Scoreboard[] scoreboard = new Scoreboard[5];
    
    //constructor
    public SaveAndLoad(Scoreboard[] scoreboard)
    {
        this.scoreboard = scoreboard;
    }
    
    public static void save() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        // 1. Create 5 GameScores
        // 2. Put 5 GameScores into a gamescore[]
        // 3. Create a Scoreboard using a gamescore[]
        
        //Create 5 instances of the Game Class
        GameScore player1 = new GameScore("Rebekah", 199);
        GameScore player2 = new GameScore("Allen", 195);
        GameScore player3 = new GameScore("Sami", 198);
        GameScore player4 = new GameScore("Megan", 142);
        GameScore player5 = new GameScore("Vince", 169);
        
        GameScore[] gamescore = new GameScore[5];
        
        gamescore[0] = player1;
        gamescore[1] = player2;
        gamescore[2] = player3;
        gamescore[3] = player4;
        gamescore[4] = player5;

        //Create an instance of the Scoreboard Class using the GameScore array
        Scoreboard scoreboard = new Scoreboard(GameScore[] gamescore);
```

The last line in this is giving me an error and I'm not sure why because those are the parameters for the Scoreboard class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer

Change to:

```
Scoreboard scoreboard = new Scoreboard(gamescore);
```

### Longer answer

Consider the code:

```
new GameScore("Vince", 169);
```

You are not doing the incorrect

```
new GameScore(String "Vince", int 169);
```

So as you know, there is no necessity to pass the variable type as well as the value, and in fact doing so is not only unnecessary but *wrong*.

### Tip

To make you code more concise you may consider writing the code as follows, eliminating the unnecessary variable names.

```
    GameScore[] gamescore = new GameScore[5];
    
    gamescore[0] = new GameScore("Rebekah", 199);
    gamescore[1] = new GameScore("Allen", 195);
    gamescore[2] = new GameScore("Sami", 198);
    gamescore[3] = new GameScore("Megan", 142);
    gamescore[4] = new GameScore("Vince", 169);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to directly print an array.
As an example:

```
        // new Bacon ( #baconId, #height, #width )

    Bacon[] baconLand = {
                        new Bacon("001", 1, 1), 
                        new Bacon("002", 1, 1), 
                        new Bacon("003", 1, 1)
                    };

    System.out.println(baconLand);
```

The result of this print statement is: [LBacon;@6f75e721

Usually we have to use `Arrays.toString(Object[] a)` to print an array. However, just using the `Arrays.toString(Object[] a)` will not work in your case unless you override the `toString()` method.

As an example, if I execute this without overriding the `toString()`  method:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(baconLand));
```

I will get this as the result: [Bacon@6f75e721, Bacon@69222c14, Bacon@606d8acf]

To show something meaningful, I can override the toString() method so that it will return the baconId:

```
    @Override
public String toString() {
    return this.baconId;
    
}
```

This method is being overridden in class Bacon (in my example).

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(baconLand));
```

The above line will now print this:
[001, 002, 003], which are the baconIds for each Bacon instance.

You can refer to this article also: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/java-array-methods-how-to-print-an-array-in-java/

Hope this helped.